# Manually display forms in formset

Tags: python, django

I would like to manually display forms in formset.

like be able to do something like {{ formset.form1 }} and have the first form displayed. 
how do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can loop over the formset to get individual forms and do whatever you would like with these forms.

```
{% for form in formset %}
    {{form.title.errors}}
    {{form.title.label}}
    {{form.title}}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

For the first form in the formset you can try the built-in filter `first`:

```
{{ formset|first }}
```

Django templates are severelly handcaped by design, you may want to check [Jinja2](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/). In Jinja you should be able to write:

```
{{ formset[0] }} {{ formset[3] }}
```

Since Django lacks a `get_item` filter, you may [write a custom filter like this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-tags):

```
@register.filter
def get_item(ob, key):
    try:
        return ob[key]
    except (TypeError, ValueError, KeyError, IndexError):
        return None
```

With this filter you should be able to write:

```
{{ formset|get_item:0 }} {{ formset|get_item:3 }}
```